# How to modify this Pytorch model for faster inference? (profiling included)

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, profiling, transformer-model

I would like to make the following transformer model a lot faster for inference on cpu, as right now takes 4.5 sec to execute (I used `summary(self.model, input_size=torch.Size([1, 256, 192])` from torchinfo)
[model code](https://github.com/sony/hFT-Transformer/blob/master/model/model_spec2midi.py)

```
=========================================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                                  Output Shape              Param #
=========================================================================================================
Model_SPEC2MIDI                                         [1, 128, 88]              --
├─Encoder_SPEC2MIDI: 1-1                                [1, 128, 256, 256]        --
│    └─Conv2d: 2-1                                      [128, 4, 256, 61]         24
│    └─Linear: 2-2                                      [128, 256, 256]           62,720
│    └─Embedding: 2-3                                   [128, 256, 256]           65,536
│    └─Dropout: 2-4                                     [128, 256, 256]           --
│    └─ModuleList: 2-5                                  --                        --
│    │    └─EncoderLayer: 3-1                           [128, 256, 256]           526,592
│    │    └─EncoderLayer: 3-2                           [128, 256, 256]           526,592
│    │    └─EncoderLayer: 3-3                           [128, 256, 256]           526,592
├─Decoder_SPEC2MIDI: 1-2                                [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Embedding: 2-6                                   [128, 88, 256]            22,528
│    └─DecoderLayer_Zero: 2-7                           [128, 88, 256]            --
│    │    └─MultiHeadAttentionLayer: 3-4                [128, 88, 256]            263,168
│    │    └─Dropout: 3-5                                [128, 88, 256]            --
│    │    └─LayerNorm: 3-6                              [128, 88, 256]            512
│    │    └─PositionwiseFeedforwardLayer: 3-7           [128, 88, 256]            262,912
│    │    └─Dropout: 3-8                                [128, 88, 256]            --
│    │    └─LayerNorm: 3-9                              [128, 88, 256]            (recursive)
│    └─ModuleList: 2-8                                  --                        --
│    │    └─DecoderLayer: 3-10                          [128, 88, 256]            789,760
│    │    └─DecoderLayer: 3-11                          [128, 88, 256]            789,760
│    └─Linear: 2-9                                      [128, 88, 1]              257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-10                                    [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Linear: 2-11                                     [128, 88, 1]              257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-12                                    [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Linear: 2-13                                     [128, 88, 1]              257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-14                                    [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Linear: 2-15                                     [128, 88, 128]            32,896
│    └─Embedding: 2-16                                  [88, 128, 256]            32,768
│    └─Dropout: 2-17                                    [88, 128, 256]            --
│    └─ModuleList: 2-18                                 --                        --
│    │    └─EncoderLayer: 3-12                          [88, 128, 256]            526,592
│    │    └─EncoderLayer: 3-13                          [88, 128, 256]            526,592
│    │    └─EncoderLayer: 3-14                          [88, 128, 256]            526,592
│    └─Linear: 2-19                                     [88, 128, 1]              257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-20                                    [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Linear: 2-21                                     [88, 128, 1]              257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-22                                    [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Linear: 2-23                                     [88, 128, 1]              257
│    └─Sigmoid: 2-24                                    [1, 128, 88]              --
│    └─Linear: 2-25                                     [88, 128, 128]            32,896
=========================================================================================================
Total params: 5,516,574
Trainable params: 5,516,574
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 688.90
=========================================================================================================
Input size (MB): 0.20
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 3820.50
Params size (MB): 22.07
Estimated Total Size (MB): 3842.77
=========================================================================================================
```

Profiling through `torch.profiler` returns

```
----------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                        Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls  
----------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
             model_inference         9.38%     430.768ms       100.00%        4.591s        4.591s             1  
                aten::matmul         1.23%      56.495ms        72.63%        3.335s      35.856ms            93  
                aten::linear         0.03%       1.353ms        55.15%        2.532s      35.667ms            71  
                    aten::mm        53.39%        2.451s        53.39%        2.451s      34.527ms            71  
                   aten::bmm        14.66%     673.043ms        14.66%     673.265ms      30.603ms            22  
               aten::softmax         0.00%     144.000us         4.67%     214.293ms      19.481ms            11  
              aten::_softmax         4.66%     214.149ms         4.66%     214.149ms      19.468ms            11  
                 aten::clone         0.02%     866.000us         4.57%     209.970ms       4.117ms            51  
                 aten::copy_         4.54%     208.307ms         4.54%     208.307ms       3.858ms            54  
             aten::clamp_min         1.69%      77.715ms         3.38%     155.278ms       8.627ms            18  
----------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 4.591s
```

While I can see the bottleneck from the profiler, I am not sure if I could make the model a lot faster than what it is now.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified the model itself is the overall bottleneck? You might be bottlenecked on loading data from disk or feature extraction pipelines.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain me better the first sentence? Yes, most of the time seems to be related to the model execution, rather than feature extraction and dataloaders. I will definitelyhave a look at thos as well, thanks